# validating multiple expressions within a until loop in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, scripting

I am getting an error when trying to evaluate multiple expressions within a until loop

I have tried multiple combinations as shown in the code section but none of them work.

Attempt 1:

```
until [ [ $http_response_code=$(curl --write-out "%{http_code}" --silent --output /dev/null "$http_url") ] = $http_success_code ]
do
     <something>
done
```

Attempt 2:

```
until [ $http_response_code=$(curl --write-out "%{http_code}" --silent --output /dev/null "$http_url") ] = [ $http_success_code ]
do
     <something>
done
```

Attempt 3:

```
until [ ($http_response_code=$(curl --write-out "%{http_code}" --silent --output /dev/null "$http_url")) = $http_success_code ]
do
     <something>
done
```

Expected - No Syntax Error
Actual - Syntax Error

Comment: `[` is a command. `[ [` is the `[` command with `[` as its first argument, which can make sense but is certainly not what you want. `http_response_code=$(...)` is an assignment of the variable `http_response_code`, but `$http_response_code=$(...)` is gibberish.

Comment: What are the "multiple expressions" you're evaluating?  It looks like you just want to evaluate the response of a single curl.

Comment: yes trying to evaluate the response of a curl and check if it matches. Can you correct the syntax?

Comment: If you just want to check the value returned by curl, just do `if curl ....; then echo curl succeeded; else echo curl failed; fi`

Comment: i have to repeat it a few times. that's why i am using until.

Comment: So do `until curl ...`

Comment: `curl` will return success if it successfully fetches a 404 page

Answer (score 1):

You can't do variable assignment in a test expression. You need to have the assignment separate from the test. Something like this could work:

```
until {
        http_response_code=$(curl --write-out "%{http_code}" --silent --output /dev/null "$http_url")
        [[ "$http_response_code" = "$http_success_code" ]]
      }; do
  <something>
done
```

Comment: Pro tip, the `{` `}` can be omitted

Comment: @ykm "didn't work" in what sense? Do you get an error, or does the test not work (and if the test doesn't work, what is `http_success_code` set to and what is `http_response_code` coming out as)?

Comment: @ykm That syntax should be ok in bash. What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: @Gordon Davisson posted my answer but not sure what happened. i don't see it. I was able to get this one working `until [ $[ http_response_code=$(curl --write-out "%{http_code}" --silent --output /dev/null $http_url_dev1) ] = $http_succes_code ]`